# Running SET command using Java

Tags: java, runtime.exec

I am executing an application using Java application (Runtime.get...) but now before running the application I have to set temp path.

```
set tmpdir=%temp%
```

Is it anyway I can execute above command using Java?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Running `set` in a separate `Runtime.exec()` invocation wouldn't help at all: it only ever affects the process that it runs in and each `exec()` call produces its own process.

What you need to do instead is provide the environment variable to your `Runtime.exec()` call using [this two](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D%29) or [three argument variant](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.io.File%29).

Better yet, scrap `Runtime.exec()` and [use `ProcessBuilder` instead](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html). With this you can simply use [`environment().put("tmpdir", "somevalue")`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html#environment%28%29) to set the environment variable you want (you can even get the value of `%temp%` from that `Map`).

Comment: Thanks a ton ..didnt know about processbuilder before...will have a shot ...thanks

Answer (score 0):

Could you execute a .cmd/.bat file rather than the app directly?